# How to add a class in document.write() method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am adding a class in document.write but it is not showing, below is my code.

```
new_window = open("","hoverwindow","width=600,height=300,left=10,top=10");
new_window.document.open();
new_window.document.write("<li>Dowload <a href=www.anylink.com class='help'></a></li>");
```

"help" is defined in my css file. Is the above syntax is correct for applying the class.

Comment: The markup in your question is invalid. There should be quotes around the value of the `href` attribute.

Comment: And what is your problem or question?

Comment: help class is created but css file may not be present in ur new browser window.

Comment: it is present, If i use this class in some td, the td is affected but not in the document.write().

Comment: is that some `td` in ur new browser window ?

Comment: @Java_NewBie: Because it's a new document. You have to include the CSS in the new document too if you want to use the `help`-class there.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, though it's not valid, browsers know to handle it.

Comment: no, that is not in the new browser window it is in the html.

Comment: @gdoron, in HTML mode, yes. In XHTML mode, not so much :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, yeah, XHTML... who uses XHTML?

Comment: @MotaBOS you were rite, css class was not included in the new browser window.

Answer (score 0):

like @FrédéricHamidi sayd:

```
new_window = open("","hoverwindow","width=600,height=300,left=10,top=10");
new_window.document.open();    
new_window.document.write("<li>Dowload <a href='www.anylink.com' class='help'></a></li>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your anchor is empty:

```
<li>Dowload <a href=www.anylink.com class='help'></a></li>
                                                 ^--------
```

Change to:

```
<li><a href="www.anylink.com" class='help'>Dowload</a></li>
                                           ^^^^^^^-------
```

Comment: that help class has an image, but the image is not showing up. If I apply this class in any of the attribute in HTML it is working but not in document.write()

Answer (score 0):

Don't use document.write - it can cause you problems:
[Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

There are other ways of injecting HTML into pages using Javacsript - .innerHTML being a good example. JavaScript libraries like jQuery also have lots of options.